# Ordering search of joined tables in 2 ways

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to search for the oldest outstanding invoice for each customer and then present the results in descending order of that invoice date however the result gives me the date of the most recent invoice. How can I ensure that it picks up the earliest invoice date? Many thanks in advance.

Here is my query:

```
$checkDebtors = "select
    a.accountNumber as accountNumber, a.balanceOutstanding as balanceOutstanding, a.companyName as companyName, b.invoiceDate as invoiceDate, b.netOutstanding as netOutstanding
from
    customersQQuote a
    Right JOIN invoices b ON a.accountNumber = b.accountNumber
WHERE   netOutstanding > 0 AND balanceOutstanding > 0
group by
    a.accountNumber
order by
     b.invoiceDate ASC";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your advice. I got some good tips from your answers which helped me solve the problem. The main thing being the use of MIN() and also that I was using Right join rather than Left. Additionally I just used the invoiceDate keyword in the ORDER BY rather than the b.invoiceDate. I guess this ensured the MIN rule was used here as well. Thanks to you I ended up getting the result I needed.

```
select
    a.accountNumber as accountNumber, a.balanceOutstanding as balanceOutstanding, a.companyName as companyName, MIN(b.invoiceDate) as invoiceDate, b.netOutstanding as netOutstanding
from
    customersQQuote a
    Left JOIN invoices b ON a.accountNumber = b.accountNumber
WHERE  netOutstanding > 0 AND balanceOutstanding > 0
group by
    a.accountNumber
order by invoiceDate ASC
```

Comment: Note that this SQL will still return possibly the wrong netOutstanding. If a customer has multiple outstanding invoices then you have specified that you want the first invoice date, but which netOutstanding is returned is not specified and could come from any row. This is the basic problem that your original SQL suffered from.

Comment: Further point, as you are checking the value of netOutstanding in the WHERE clause which comes from the invoices table, you have in effect done an INNER JOIN not a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the result by following sql? Try it, if it does not work for you, leave a comment for me;)

```
select
    a.accountNumber as accountNumber,
    a.balanceOutstanding as balanceOutstanding,
    a.companyName as companyName,
    b.invoiceDate as invoiceDate,
    c.netOutstanding as netOutstanding
from
    (SELECT accountNumber, MIN(invoiceDate) AS invoiceDate FROM invoices GROUP BY accountNumber) b
    LEFT JOIN customersQQuote a ON a.accountNumber = b.accountNumber
    LEFT JOIN invoices c ON c.accountNumber = b.accountNumber AND c.invoiceDate = b.invoiceDate
WHERE   c.netOutstanding > 0 AND a.balanceOutstanding > 0
group by
    a.accountNumber
order by
     b.invoiceDate ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Reno, this gave me the correct order in the results and the correct invoices but it only gave me 11 out of the 212 results. I think the fact that it was looking into the invoices first it may move on to the next customer before finding a netOutsanding > 0. However I got what I needed from you.

Answer (score 0):

Above code has certain mistakes such as, alias name using in where clause and misuse of group by clause. you can apply this piece of code..

```
select a.accountNumber as accountNumber, a.balanceOutstanding as balanceOutstanding,
a.companyName as companyName, b.invoiceDate as invoiceDate, b.netOutstanding as netOutstanding
from customersQQuote a Right JOIN invoices b ON a.accountNumber = b.accountNumber
WHERE b.netOutstanding > 0 AND a.balanceOutstanding > 0 order by b.invoiceDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code does not work as you have not specified which invoice to pull back. You have used GROUP BY accountNumber, so it will return one row for each accountNumber value. Other fields should be aggregate values (ie, the result of a aggregate function such as MIN() or MAX()). If fields are neither mentioned in the GROUP BY clause nor the result of an aggregate function then MySQL will return a value for that column, but which row that value comes from is not defined. It could be the first or the last rows value, or any in between (and could change between different versions of MySQL).

Most flavours of SQL do not allow a query like this and would error. MySQL has a feature that does allow this. But this feature can be configured to be turned off.

To do this in standard SQL and give you a consistent value you use a sub query to get the first invoiceDate for each accountNumber, using the MIN() aggregate function. Then you join this sub query against the invoices table to get the other columns.

```
SELECT a.accountNumber, 
        a.balanceOutstanding, 
        a.companyName, 
        b.invoiceDate, 
        b.netOutstanding
FROM
( 
    SELECT accountNumber, 
            MIN(invoiceDate) as invoiceDate
    FROM invoices
    GROUP BY accountNumber
) sub0
INNER JOIN invoices b ON sub0.account_number = b.account_number AND sub0.invoiceDate = b.invoiceDate
INNER JOIN customersQQuote a ON sub0.account_number = a.account_number
```

Note that if an accountNumber could have 2 identical first invoiceDate values then you will need to pick another field to minimise (ie, maybe your unique id field) for each date. Gets messy but something like this:-

```
SELECT a.accountNumber, 
        a.balanceOutstanding, 
        a.companyName, 
        b.invoiceDate, 
        b.netOutstanding
FROM
( 
    SELECT accountNumber, 
            MIN(invoiceDate) as invoiceDate
    FROM invoices
    GROUP BY accountNumber
) sub0
INNER JOIN
( 
    SELECT accountNumber, 
            invoiceDate,
            MIN(id) as id
    FROM invoices
    GROUP BY accountNumber, invoiceDate
) sub1 ON sub0.accountNumber = sub1.accountNumber AND sub0.invoiceDate = sub1.invoiceDate
INNER JOIN invoices b ON sub1.account_number = b.account_number AND sub1.invoiceDate = b.invoiceDate AND sub1.id = b.id
INNER JOIN customersQQuote a ON sub0.account_number = a.account_number
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and explanation Kickstart, unfortunately this gave me 648 results out of the expected 212. It included customers who's balanceOutstanding was 0. I have solved the problem and answered it above.

Comment: @NickDale - if you can post some sample data I will sort the issue. It is trivial to add a WHERE clause to check the value of netOutstanding.